# apache tomcat 9 eclipse Kepler IDE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat9, eclipse-kepler

I installed apache tomcat 9 to use it with eclipse IDE.

1*When i try to add in "servers" tab i don't find it. (the latest version found is 8.0).

2*I tried adding it manually in Windows->preferences->server->runtime environement By chosing 8.0 version and introducing **tomcat 9.0** installation path istead of 8.0 path but it doesn't accept it showing this message 
" The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 9.0.35.  A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected."

3* I uninstalled tomcat and reinstalled it in the default folder (thinking that this was the problems origin), but nothing.

those are the solution i tried. **Have any one faced this problem or resolved it?**

***Additionnal informations:***

**OS version**: Windows 10 64bits

**Eclipse**: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
         Version: Kepler Service Release 2
         Build id: 20140224-0627

**tomcat**: 9.0.35

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Tomcat 9 did not exist when Eclipse Kepler was the supported version. Get the current version: 2020-03.

Comment: @nitinid I installed it ( the 2020-03 version), it's telling me this "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified." :/

Comment: Use the downloadable Tomcat zip file instead of the installed location. https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F